# MUI: How to prevent Grid items from going on next row?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, grid

I am using MUI `Grid` structure in ReactJs to display 5 columns like this:

[image]

In smaller screens the columns are moving in the next row. But In smaller screens I also want all the columns to show in one row only and I can access other columns by scrolling horizontally.

```js
<Grid
  container
  spacing={2}
  style={{
    maxHeight: "100vh",
    overflowY: "auto",
    overflowX: "hidden",
    height: "440px",
    overflow: "auto",
  }}
>
  <Grid item xs={2.1}>
    {cards.map((card) => <Card props={card} /> )}
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `Grid` [uses flexbox](https://mui.com/components/grid/#how-it-works) under the hood. You can simply set the [`wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap#values) value to `nowrap` in your `Grid` container, you can see the full API of `Grid` component [here](https://mui.com/api/grid/).

```js
<Grid
  container
  wrap="nowrap" // --> add this line to disable wrap
  sx={{ overflow: "auto" }} // --> add scrollbar when the content inside is overflowed
  spacing={8}
>
  {...}
</Grid>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66944361/how-to-prevent-columns-to-go-on-next-row-in-material-ui-grid-structure]

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Grid is based on a 12-column grid layout. Therefore xs accepts only the following values:

`'auto' | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12`.

I would recommend you to place an empty grid with an xs size equal to 1 at the beginning and end. That brings you to a total size of xs equal to 12.

```js
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={2}
            style={{
              maxHeight: "100vh",
              overflowY: "auto",
              overflowX: "hidden",
              height: "440px",
              overflow: "auto",
            }}
          >
               <Grid item xs={1}/>
                 {cards.map((card) => (
                   <Grid item xs={2}>
                     <Card props={card} />
                   </Grid>
                  ))}
               <Grid item xs={1}/>
          </Grid>
```

Comment: Actually. It's working fine for laptop/pc screens. But in small screens the column are moving in next rows. I have to prevent that. I want all the columns in one row in small screens also so that I can scroll horizontally to view other columns

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this: [https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/#single-line-grid-list](https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/#single-line-grid-list)?